# Разные запросы в одном роутере express

Tags: post, get, express, роутер

Как организовать разные запросы в одном `routers` файле **tests.js**. Делаю так:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {

    //здесь ищу данные Test из mongoose - mongoDB.
    Test.find( { title: "yanix" }, function(err, data) {
        if (data) res.send(data); //все работает
    });

});


router.post('/', function (req, res) {

    var myTitle = req.body.title;
    //дальше что-то делаю с MyTitle
    //обратно ничего не отправляю
    //ничего не работет
    //var myTitle = "ловим баг"; //даже так

});

module.exports = router;
```

Добавил следующие строки в **app.js**. Вроде все правильно:

```
var test1 = require('./routes/tests');
app.use('/tests', test1);
```

В `jade` шаблоне странички есть стандартная форма, отправляющая запрос `POST`

```
form(name="add-estimation", action="/tests", method="post")
  div.input
    span.label Title
    input(type="text", name="title")
  div.actions
    input(type="submit", value="add")
```

Скрипт, который ловит `GET` запрос в поряде:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "/tests", true);
x.onload = function (){
    console.log( x.responseText);
    alert( x.responseText);
};
x.send(null);
```

С таким кодом в консоль и алерт вылезает html-код сгенерированный на сервере странички. Причем магическим образом только после того, как обновиться страничку. На первом заходе - все норм.

Comment: у тебя `"/tests2"` в запросе

Comment: `вылезает какая-то белиберда` добавьте и ее в вопрос.

Comment: /tests2 был собсно для теста. Изменил пост.
Это вообще нормальная практика так складывать роуты?

Comment: /tests2 - это опечатка.

Comment: В вопросе вполне рабочая конструкция, роуты работают. Видимо Вы где-то рендерите ответ раньше (через middleware?).

Comment: Aid, спасибо. То, что роуты рабочие - это то, что мне нужно было услышать и работать дальше над остальным кодом.